# R POSIXct returns NA with "03/12/2017 02:17:13"

Tags: r, posixct

I have a data set containing the following date, along with several others

```
03/12/2017 02:17:13
```

I want to put the whole data set into a data table, so I used `read_csv` and `as.data.table` to create DT which contained the date/time information in date. 
Next I used

```
DT[, date := as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")]
```

Everything looked fine except I had some NA values where the original data had dates. The following expression returns an NA

```
as.POSIXct("03/12/2017 02:17:13", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

The question is why and how to fix.

Comment: You may have to provide data to show us where this is happening. My thought is that you may have a spacing issue in those values when they are strings, but I can't confirm until I see some examples

Comment: I suspect this is a bug in `.Internal(as.POSIXct(x, tz))`. If you trace `as.POSIXct(x, format, tz="America/Denver")`, it first calls `as.POSIXlt(...)` which works, and then calls `as.POSIXct.POSIXlt` which does not. Odd.

Comment: I don't think its either a bug or bad typing on my part. There really is no 2 to 3 am on the morning when daylight savings kicks in. Go to this link (https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/united-states-colorado-denver-to-utc) and set it to March 12, 2017. The clock keeps ticking, but what would have been 2 am MST is now 3 am MDT.

Answer (score 2):

Just use functions `anytime()` or `utctime()` from package [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime)

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime("03/12/2017 02:17:13")
[1] "2017-03-12 01:17:13 CST"
R>
```

or

```
R> utctime("03/12/2017 02:17:13")
[1] "2017-03-11 20:17:13 CST"
R>
```

The real crux is that time did not exists in North America due to DST. You could parse it as UTC as UTC does not observer daylight savings:

```
R> utctime("03/12/2017 02:17:13", tz="UTC")
[1] "2017-03-12 02:17:13 UTC"
R>
```

You can express that UTC time as Mountain time, but it gets you the previous day:

```
R> utctime("03/12/2017 02:17:13", tz="America/Denver")
[1] "2017-03-11 19:17:13 MST"
R>
```

Ultimately, you (as the analyst) have to provide as to what was measured. UTC would make sense, the others may need adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below but ways to improve appreciated.

The explanation for the NA is that in the mountain time zone in the US, that date and time is in the window of the switch to daylight savings where the time doesn't exist, hence NA. While the time zone is not explicitly specified, I guess R must be picking it up from the computer's time, which is in "America/Denver"

The solution is to explicitly state the date/time string is in UTC and then convert back as follows:

```
time.utc <- as.POSIXct("03/12/2017 02:17:13", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

> time.utc
[1] "2017-03-12 02:17:13 UTC"
>
```

Next, add 6 hours to the UTC time which is the difference between UTC and MST

```
time.utc2 <- time.utc + 6 * 60 * 60

> time.utc2
[1] "2017-03-12 08:17:13 UTC"
>
```

Now convert to America/Denver time using daylight savings.

```
time.mdt <- format(time.utc2, usetz = TRUE, tz = "America/Denver")

> time.mdt
[1] "2017-03-12 01:17:13 MST"
>
```

Note that this is in standard time, because daylight savings doesn't start until 2 am.

If you change the original string from 2 am to 3 am, you get the following

```
> time.mdt
[1] "2017-03-12 03:17:13 MDT"
>
```

The hour between 2 and 3 is lost in the change from standard to daylight savings but the data are now correct.