# Error when converting to POSIXct: some dates return NA

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have this df:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
                                      1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("2018-03-24 00:24:14", "2018-03-24 00:54:00", 
                                                                  "2018-03-24 12:19:00", "2018-03-24 14:04:01", "2018-03-24 17:12:35", 
                                                                  "2018-03-24 18:58:57", "2018-03-24 20:48:50", "2018-03-24 21:37:42", 
                                                                  "2018-03-25 01:55:40", "2018-03-25 02:47:58", "2018-03-25 03:35:11"
                                      ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to convert the dates to POSIXct:

```
df  <- df %>%
  mutate(date=as.POSIXct(date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
```

It seems to have worked:

```
class(df$date)
> class(df$date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

BUT... As you can see, one date returned a NA:

```
df
                  date
1  2018-03-24 14:04:01
2  2018-03-24 18:58:57
3  2018-03-24 20:48:50
4  2018-03-24 21:37:42
5  2018-03-25 01:55:40
6                 <NA>
7  2018-03-25 03:35:11
8  2018-03-24 00:24:14
9  2018-03-24 00:54:00
10 2018-03-24 17:12:35
11 2018-03-24 12:19:00
```

Why?

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Switzerland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_Switzerland.1252
```

Thank you

Comment: Note the full df has thousands of dates, and that the problem above occurs in only 3 cases. But I'd still like to know why...

Comment: What about using `lubridate::ymd_hms()`?

Comment: It is working correctly for me

Comment: That is a likely FAQ -- the NA times can occur when the daylight savings time happens and you "spring forward" making it a one hour gap.

Comment: don't know the proper dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606738/r-posixct-returns-na-with-03-12-2017-021713/44606739#44606739 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787374/how-to-convert-a-very-large-dataset-to-xts-as-xts-fails-on-1-5m-rows/50911396#50911396 probably several others ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@DirkEddelbuettel* mentioned in comments it's a daylight saving issue.

```
df$date
# [1] "2018-03-24 14:04:01 CET" 
# [2] "2018-03-24 18:58:57 CET" 
# [3] "2018-03-24 20:48:50 CET" 
# [4] "2018-03-24 21:37:42 CET" 
# [5] "2018-03-25 01:55:40 CET" 
# [6] "2018-03-25 02:47:58"        ##
# [7] "2018-03-25 03:35:11 CEST"
# [8] "2018-03-24 00:24:14 CET" 
# [9] "2018-03-24 00:54:00 CET" 
# [10] "2018-03-24 17:12:35 CET" 
# [11] "2018-03-24 12:19:00 CET"
```

`as.POSIXct` appears to correctly refuse to convert the sixth time, because it simply may not have existed.

```
as.POSIXct("2018-03-25 02:47:58", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] NA
```

If you nevertheless want to use the time you may use `strptime`.

```
strptime("2018-03-25 02:47:58", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2018-03-25 02:47:58"
```

The whole thing:

```
df <- transform(df, date=strptime(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
df
#                   date
# 1  2018-03-24 14:04:01
# 2  2018-03-24 18:58:57
# 3  2018-03-24 20:48:50
# 4  2018-03-24 21:37:42
# 5  2018-03-25 01:55:40
# 6  2018-03-25 02:47:58
# 7  2018-03-25 03:35:11
# 8  2018-03-24 00:24:14
# 9  2018-03-24 00:54:00
# 10 2018-03-24 17:12:35
# 11 2018-03-24 12:19:00
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 11 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ date: POSIXlt, format:  ...
```

Also possible with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% mutate(df, date=strptime(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Any idea why the other solution produces a NA?

Comment: @johnjohn You're welcome! Yeah, please see edited answer and _DirkEddelbuettel_'s comment.